# How to set math.random in between sets of numbers

Tags: javascript

My attempts at setting a Math.random value in between a set of numbers has failed numerous times and have no clue on how to execute this.

What i have previously tried is to set math.floor(Math.random()* 400) - 200; to see if the function would get a number between 400 and 200.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) - 200;
```

But the function ended up taking the number given and subtracted by 200

Comment: you can use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 200 ;` it generates a number btw 0 -200 and sums other 200 to get numbers between 200-400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `Math.random() * 200 + 200;`

Answer (score 0):

Try Math.floor((Math.random()+1) * 200);